# A possible generalization of Pitt's theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Inspired by Pitt's theorem and  [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443800/what-standard-banach-space-is-isomorphic-to-the-completion-of-this-different-nor)  we ask the following  question:

First we remind the Pitt's theorem and also introduce a particular Banach space as averaging of  $\ell^p$ spaces for $1\leq p \leq 2$

**Pitt's theorem:** Every bounded operator $T:\ell^q \to \ell^p$, $p<q$ is a  compact  operator.

Now consider $X=\ell_1$  with new norm $|x|=\int_1^2 |x|_pdp$ the completion of this normed space is denoted by $\tilde{X}$.

**Question:** Assume that $T:\tilde{X}\to \ell^1$ is a bounded operator. Is $T$ necessarilly a compact operator?

Comment: How would this be a generalization (rather than an "adaptation") of Pitt's theorem?

Comment: If the space contains a complemented subspace isomorphic to $l^1$ then clearly the answer is no.